# node - using jest with esm package

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I was wondering how I would incorporate the `esm` package https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm with jest on a node backend.

I tried setting up a setup file with `require("esm")` and `require("esm")(module)` at the very top of the file, but it's still giving me the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` error.

I would have previously used `node -r esm` but jest doesn't support this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you perform `require("esm")(module)`, think of it as you are creating an esm-transformer function that is pending a file to be transformed into an ES module.

Here's my attempt with node v8+ with:

- default `jest` configuration
- default `esm` configuration

[image]

utils-1.js:

```
export const add = (a, b) => a + b;
```

utils-2.js:

```
export const multiAdd = array => array.reduce((sum, next) => sum + next, 0)
```

_test_/utils-1.assert.js

```
import { add } from '../utils-1';

describe('add(a,b)', () => {
  it('should return the addtion of its two inputs', () => {
    expect(add(1,2)).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

_test_/utils-2.assert.js

```
import { multiAdd } from '../utils-2';

describe('multiAdd(<Number[]>)', () => {
  it('should return a summation of all array elements', () => {
    expect(multiAdd([1,2,3,4])).toBe(10);
  })
});
```

_test_/utils.test.js

```
const esmImport = require('esm')(module);
const utils_1 = esmImport('./utils-1.assert')
const utils_2 = esmImport('./utils-2.assert')
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: this makes a lot more sense to me than the documentation.

Comment: Actually, multiAdd can simply be ```array.reduce(add,0)```

Comment: I have done this but for some reason I loose the jest variable, so I cannot do jest.spyOn for example

Comment: @GiancarloCorzo Reassigning the jest global appears to fix that issue:
   `const originalJest = jest;
   const esmImport = require('esm')(module);
   global.jest = originalJest`

Comment: What? You aren't even using the `esm` package in this example. How is this an accepted answer?

Comment: @AndrewKoster - The esm module is being used, but like this: `const esmImport = require('esm')(module);`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking, the accepted answer does require a bit of effort.

You can also use the `esm` package with `jest` by transforming esm files back to cjs using `jest-esm-transformer-2` (or `jest-esm-transformer` if you are using `jest` < 28)

1. Install the package `npm i jest-esm-transformer-2 --save-dev`
2. Create your `jest.config.js` in the root directory and configure code transform to use `jest-esm-transformer-2`

```js
const config = {
  transform: {
    '.js': 'jest-esm-transformer-2'
  }
}

module.exports = config
```

3. Run `jest` with no flags etc.