# Loosing jest variable when using esm package

Tags: jestjs

I followed this answer to make jest work with esm packages

[node - using jest with esm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095199/node-using-jest-with-esm-package/53194212#53194212)

But I get an error when I try to do jest.SpyOn because it said that jest is undefined.

I did some digging and notice that jest is present on my app.test.js file but not in the asserts.js

So I was wondering how can I get the jest variable on the assert file or can I import jest directly without relaying on injecting it like the default config